# How I can relate objectstore in IndexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

I have created a data base with 2 IndexedDB object stores .
That way I could relate as if it were a foreing key .
The database contains an object store called patients and the other is called evidence then wanted to add tests associated with patients.

[Photo DataBase IndexedDb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcuuc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In indexedDB itself you can not build a relation between 2 objectStores. IndexedDB is no relational database system. If you want the have a relation, you have to implement this relation in your javascript code.

If you have an 2 objectStores i.e. containing the objects:

```
patient = {"number":"1234", name:"Michael Foo"}; // where "number"is the key
evidence = {"id":"1","content":"yes, its true","patientId":"1234"}; // where "id" is the key
```

you can define "patientId" as an [Index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/index). So you can lookup for "patientId".
If you need both together, you make a query for patient, and then you use the "number" value to make a query for the index "patientId". So you have both.

If you i.e. want to delete data form 2 objectStores and you want to go for sure, that the values in both objectStores will be deleted, you can do this in one [transaction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction). so if one part of a transaction throws an error, you can cancel the hole transaction, to rollback...